# opencart controller variable in view

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

i want to add custom variable in /controller/customer/customer.php editor, so i added

```
$data['entry_limit'] = $this->language->get('entry_limit');
```

so basically i should be able to use $entry_limit in /view/../customer/customer_form.tpl since that controller binds to this .tpl file (checked it), but problem is that it gives error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: entry_limit
```

I'm sure that i have edited all langs and that lang variable is there, so there is not a problem getting it...
what can i do?

OC Version: 2.1

Comment: Could you post your controller method that responsible for this issue? And which version of OpenCart you are using?

Comment: can you verify that the variable `$data['entry_limit'] = $this->language->get('entry_limit');` is being set in the `getForm()` function (in customer controller) as that will be the one binding that `customer_form.tpl` file. If its in another function then it won't be available to use on the template.

Comment: no, im not editing custom controller... and yes its in getForm() function

Comment: P.S i am editing admin controller file

Comment: Alfa, its default controller located in admin/catalog/controller ...

Comment: the language method `get()` will *always* return something - even if the variable is not defined in the language file.  with that in mind there is only one possible reason why this would happen: you not editing the code that calls that view.

Comment: billynoah, not possible, i see that output ($this->response->setOutput($this->load->view(...)) calls right .tpl file where i'm placing my values... i know that language always gets something, but problem is that variable is somehow not defined in controller to be called in view... in theory it is impossible since data[] is transferred to view, but well :D we see the fact

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because that you have installed some modification.

try to refresh the modification under admin > extensions > modifications > click on blue refresh button in top right corner.